# How do I handle Excel Errors with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I run a variety of scripts that grab information using Selenium and throw them into Excel Sheets.  The code always works fine.  For example:

```
FireFox driver = new FireFoxDriver();
activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text = driver.findElement(By.XPath("abc123")).Text;
```

However, with any user interaction, for examaple, when I right click an Excel cell or highlight a column when (I think) Selenium is trying to input data, it gets caught up/confused on where to actually place the data and Excel crashes.  Is there a way to handle errors where the user interacting with Excel does not cause the program to crash?

Comment: Tell them not to interact with their computers when running automated tests?  That's QA Automation 101...

Comment: @Taegost  After countless attempts, I do not think they will ever listen, but if that is the only solution, I'll keep at it.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Selenium to know a programmatic resolution, and I definitely feel your pain

Comment: I don't see how it can be considered an automated *test* if humans are able to interfere. Selenium is, I think, well within its rights to not tolerate that kind of thing. Are you sure you can't solve this with a simple HTTP request rather than needing a real browser? Would change the way you interact with Excel naturally.

Comment: @AndrewRegan  I am not too too familiar with HTTP Requests (although I am slowly learning them) and I have not used that as a solution just yet, I was hoping there was some type of C# Library that would magically handle the Excel errors that I did not know about.